# Stuck on the inverse of a function

Tags: inverse

I am stuck in trying to inverse this function:

$f(x) = x-(x-0.75)^2+a\ln((x-0.75)^2+1)$

Where $x\in(0.75;1.25)$.

Does anybody has an idea of the solution? Is there a method you advice?
I tried on wolfram alpha, but it is not finding any solution.

Many thanks!

Comment: First of all have you checked that the function is bijective on the given interval whatever the value of $a$ ? Then, it is almost sure that there is no explicit expression for the inverse function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need to work a bit more on this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the inverse function (if it exists, I didn't check this) cannot be written using elementary functions, as you would need to solve the equation for x.